# How to theme menus in a custom twig

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

I've fetched the main menu for the website using the code below.

```
public function build() {
    $menu_name = 'main';
    $menu_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();
    $parameters = $menu_tree->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters($menu_name);
    $parameters->setMinDepth(0);
    $tree = $menu_tree->load($menu_name, $parameters);
    $manipulators = array(
      array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkAccess'),
      array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:generateIndexAndSort'),
    );
    $tree = $menu_tree->transform($tree, $manipulators);
    $build['menu'] = $menu_tree->build($tree);


return array(
      '#theme' => 'allofus_menu_footer',
      '#build' => $build,
    );
  }
```

I'm trying to put it as a block, but I want to show it as a 2 coloumn. In the first coloumn, first main menu and its sub menus and the rest of main and sub menus in the second coloumn.

I've created a twig but it does not print anything except markup. I've tried to foreach but it is not working.

`allofus-menu-footer.html.twig`:

```
{% if build %}
    <nav id ="secondary-menu" class="navigation" role="navigation">
        {{ build }}
    </nav>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a lot of this with [Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block). I prefer [Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) as it is a little more flexible and offers more template suggestions and hooks than the core menu module. It kind of looks like you are building your own block above, I can't tell, but you can save time by using [Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) in that case.

In one of my menus, this is the twig file that handles the output. I did not do any preprocess or extra stuff, just built around the macro concept used in `menu.html.twig`. Every parent item has children, and if those children items exceed 7, it will start a new list. For example, if the menu link has 14 children, then my code will have a drop down consisting of 2 unordered lists with 7 links each. Our style then makes them into columns. This is a little different from your use case, but should get you on the right track.

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override to display a menu.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - menu_name: The machine name of the menu.
 * - items: A nested list of menu items. Each menu item contains:
 *   - attributes: HTML attributes for the menu item.
 *   - below: The menu item child items.
 *   - title: The menu link title.
 *   - url: The menu link url, instance of \Drupal\Core\Url
 *   - localized_options: Menu link localized options.
 *   - is_expanded: TRUE if the link has visible children within the current
 *     menu tree.
 *   - is_collapsed: TRUE if the link has children within the current menu tree
 *     that are not currently visible.
 *   - in_active_trail: TRUE if the link is in the active trail.
 */
#}
{% import _self as menus %}

{#
  We call a macro which calls itself to render the full tree.
  @see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html
#}
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    <ul>
      {% for item in items %}
        {%
          set classes = [
            'global-top__utility-item',
            'js-utility-item',
            item.in_active_trail ? 'active-trail',
            item.below ? 'has-submenu'
          ]
        %}

        <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
          {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
          {% if item.below %}
            {{ menus.submenu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
          {% endif %}
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{% macro submenu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  <div class="global-top__submenu">
    {% for chunk in items|batch(7) %}
      <ul class="global-top__submenu-col">
        {% for item in chunk %}
          <li{{ item.attributes }}>
            {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: This does not make menus in 2 coloumns bro

Comment: It does if you use markup and style to do it, which is what the `chunk | batch` line is doing. The style is making them into columns. The batch creates a new `ul` list every 7 items. If my menu had 21 children, there would be 3 columns in our drop down.